# Remainder term of Taylor polynomial in matrix calculus

Tags: calculus, matrices, taylor-expansion

This is my first time asking a question here and it might be rather specific. Hopefully there is still someone who can answer.

Assume for a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is at least one time differentiable that we have the Taylor approximation $ f(x) = f(a) + f'(x)(x-a) + r_a(X) $ with $  r_a(x) = O(|x-a|)         $.

The question now becomes: Are there results concerning the error term when instead of scalars we plug in $n \times n$ symmetric, positive definite matrices X and A (assume that all the operations are well defined, e.g. inverses exist if neccessary)
\begin{align}
  f(X) = f(A) + f'(A)(X-A) + r_A(X),
\end{align}
such that for example $\|r_A(X)\| = O(\|X - A\|)$?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one correction. The approximation is not only $O$ but also $o$ for a one time differentiable map:
$$r_a(x) = o(|x-a|)$$

Then coming back to your question, if $V, W$ are two Banach normed spaces, you can define the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) for a map $f : V \to W$. And you'll have also $$f(X) = f(A) + f'(A)(X-A) + o(\Vert X-A \Vert_V)$$

You can apply this to the Banach space of $n$-dimensional real matrices. And plug in positive definite matrices in the formula. Just take car that the set of positive definite matrices itself is not a vector space.

Comment: In your correction, you still have the big $O$. One should mention that $f'(A)(X-A)$ is not a matrix-matrix product but some matrix-valued linear function in matrix space. Take $f(X)=X^2$ as example.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your solution! First I was considering using the matrix calculus directly to evaluate the Taylor approximation (but as stated above, I don't think its that simple to make sense of the expression r_A(X) in this case), but after a bit of investigation I think the derivative you suggested will work out nicely for what I'm trying to do.